# how to teach vim indent like this

Tags: javascript, vim, indentation

```
var Comments = new Schema({
    title     : String
  , body      : String
  , date      : Date
});

var BlogPost = new Schema({
    author    : ObjectId
  , title     : String
  , body      : String
  , date      : Date
  , comments  : [Comments]
  , meta      : {
        votes : Number
      , favs  : Number
    }
});
```

my vim now indents like this:

```
Offer = new Schema({
          'title': {type: String},
          'discount': {type: String},
});
```

Comment: Perhaps, this would be better asked on http://superuser.com/

Comment: why? it's relative programming topic. My nodejs jobs need changing indents in my vim.

Comment: Please paste contents of `let @+=join([&autoindent, &smartindent, &cindent, &indentexpr], ", ")` (this puts it in the X clipboard from gvim)

Comment: 1, 1, 1, EclimGetJavascriptIndent(v:lnum)

Comment: Your commas at the beginning of the line make my eyes bleed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

thanks guys, i've installed new indent file for javascript from this github repo:
[JavaScript Indent : Javascript indenter (HTML indent is included)](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3081)